# Manually set up Entity Framework's Table per type inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type

I have some existing tables and models that were set up manually, that is just relying on Entity's implicit associations.  I have no edmx files or designers or mapping wizards.

I would like to set up an inheritance association by Table per Type so that I can have a base class represented by one table, and then have additional tables representing the additional fields for inherited classes.  Is there a way I can do this with just models and tables.  By default Entity tries to access the structure as table per hierarchy, and throws an error because the inherited class members are not present in the table that represents the base class.

So for example:

```
public class FormBase
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string FormType { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public int? Hidden { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateFinalized { get; set; }
}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FormBases] (
    [Id]            BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [FormType]      NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Status]        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Hidden]        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [DateSubmitted] DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [DateFinalized] DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

public class CheckRequestModel : FormBase
{
    [Display(Name="Requester Name")]
    public string RequestorName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string PayToName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Address")]
    public string PayToAddress { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="City")]
    public string PayToCity { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="State")]
    public string PayToState { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Zip")]
    public int PayToZip { get; set; }

    public bool ReceiptAttached { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Receipt")]
    public Attachment Receipt { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Receipt")]
    public long? ReceiptId { get; set; }

    public bool InvoiceAttached { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Invoice")]
    public Attachment Invoice { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Invoice")]
    public long? InvoiceId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Date")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Total Amount")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public Decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Purchase Requisition Type")]
    public string PurchaseRequisitionType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Purpose Description")]
    public string PurposeDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Allocations")]
    public List<AllocationInformation> Allocations { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Allocation Total")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public Decimal? AllocationTotal { get; set; }
}


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CheckRequestModels] (
    [Id]                      BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]                  INT            NOT NULL,
    [Status]                  INT            NOT NULL,
    [DateSubmitted]           DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [DateFinalized]           DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [FormType]                NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT ('CheckRequest') NULL,
    [Hidden]                  INT            NULL,
    [RequestorName]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Email]                   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PayToName]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PayToAddress]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PayToCity]               NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PayToState]              NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PayToZip]                INT            NOT NULL,
    [ReceiptAttached]         BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceAttached]         BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Date]                    DATETIME2 (7)  NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmount]             DECIMAL (18)   NOT NULL,
    [PurchaseRequisitionType] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PurposeDescription]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [AllocationTotal]         DECIMAL (18)   NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceId]               INT            NULL,
    [ReceiptId]               INT            NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Currently I still have the fields from the base class in the inherited table.  Would entity figure out what I want if I remove those or do I need to do something else?

Comment: I have a tutorial at http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/entity-framework-code-first-inheritance, see if it helps.

Comment: Ok, so I just need to annotate with the `[Table("Name")]` annotation?

Comment: Ok I tried that and I think it's almost working, but it keeps looking for a Discriminator column, as if it's still using hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `DbSet` as a collection of abstract type, then map the derived type to another table:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FormBase> Forms { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CheckRequestModel>().Map(r => {
            r.ToTable("CheckRequests");
        });
    }
}
```

This will do the trick.